# Highcharts drilldown in stacked area chart

Tags: highcharts, stacked-area-chart

Is it possible to have a stacked area chart with drilldown? I want to drilldown to another series on clicking on an area. Any simple example would be highly appreciated.

```
JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/UKC83/1/
```

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/async/

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I want to do it in stacked area chart. I have tried it. Here you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/UKC83/1/. If you click top left point, drilldown will work. But I want this drilldown to work if anyone clicks on whole blue area, not just a point.

Comment: Unforutnaltey click event is available only on the points or line of serie. Not on the "fillarea"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I have implemented drilldown in stacked area chart:

```
JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/UKC83/2/
```